# Showing parts of a sitemap in different LocGroup

Tags: scala, lift

I have a problem with the LocGroup in Liftweb 3.0.

The main goal is to show a normal user Menu like this:

```
val userMenu = List(
    Menu("First") / "100_first" / "100_first_main" submenus (
    Menu("First_Sub") / "100_first" / "100_first_sub" submenus (
    Menu("First_Sub_Sub") / "100_first" / "220_first_sub_sub" submenus (
```

etc. etc.

In addition there has to be some kind of "service-menu" which should be shown in a different `div` on the template:

```
val serviceMenu = List(Menu("Impressum") / "about" / "index" >> Hidden >> LocGroup("servicenav"))
```

The "user" Sitemap shows as it should be, but the "service-menu" doesn't. What am I missing since this is the same approach as in the documentation?

---

My template which surrounds the mail html file:

```
<div id="servicenavblock">
    <div id="servicenav">
        <div data-lift="Menu.group?group=servicenav">Service-Navigation</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

The creation of the Sitemap in `Boot.scala`:

```
LiftRules.setSiteMap(SiteMap(Menus.siteMap: _*))
```

And finally the `index.html`:

```
<body data-lift-content-id="content">
<div id="content" data-lift="surround?with=default;at=snippet_content">
    <h2>Willkommen</h2>
</div>
</body>
```

Comment: It looks like the Menu.group snippet uses the node it is invoked from as its template, and by default expects <li data-lift="Menu.group...etc"><a>link</a></li>. See https://github.com/lift/framework/blob/master/web/webkit/src/main/scala/net/liftweb/builtin/snippet/Menu.scala#L356

Comment: Great, thank you, with this template it works. Maybe the liftweb-people should someday update their docs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to the comment from [Brett](https://stackoverflow.com/users/807730/brett) this is the working HTML-Template:

```
<div id="servicenav">
    <div>
        <ul>
            <li data-lift="Menu.group?group=servicenav;eager_eval=true"><a>Service</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
</div>
```